# Webpack with static/marketing sites (non SPA)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, static-site

so I have to make a couple of static/marketing sites and I'd like to use webpack as a module bundler.

So I was thinking about a directory structure like this:

```
build/
src/
  html/
    index.html
    foo.html
    bar.html
  scss/
    main.scss
    _partial1.scss
  js/
    app.js
    foo.js
  fonts/
    fonta.ttf
  images/
    img1.png
    svg1.svg
```

What I basically want for every HTML is to have something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="bundle.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- html static content -->
  <script src="bundle.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I was thinking to use https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin so I can copy the files inside `src/html` into `build` and build css/js into `/build` too to end up with a file structure like:

```
build/
  index.html
  about.html
  foo.html
  bar.html
  build.js
  build.css
```

Also I was thinking about using https://github.com/tapio/live-server to serve everything is inside `build/`.

That being said, every change I made on any `.scss / .js / .html` will be copied over to the `build/` folder

Thoughts on this approach? I think it's alright for serving static/marketing sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to that folder structure, I would use another:

```
build/
html/
    index.html
    foo.html
    bar.html
src/
    scss/
        main.scss
        _partial1.scss
    js/
        app.js
        foo.js
    fonts/
        fonta.ttf
    images/
        img1.png
        svg1.svg
```

And in your HTML files you can simply write:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="bundle/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- html static content -->
        <script src="bundle/app.js" />
    </body>
</html>
```

So you just need to generate your bundled JS and CSS files into `build` and don't need to copy the HTML files every time you bundle with webpack.

Comment: Hmmm I don't like the fact of having another folder different than `src/` for adding my code. I like the idea of moving the HTML inside the `build/` folder  because I don't see any benefit from just copy pasting the html from inside `src/html` to `build`.

Comment: but you have no benefit from let your html be copied from `src` to `build` folder neither, if your HTML files are static